# Compile PHP with readline support on a mac?

Tags: php, macos, unix, compilation, installation

I'm trying to compile PHP 7.2.3 and install clean into `/usr/local` with `readline` support, so that `php -a` will give an interactive shell session.

I keep getting the error

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_append_history", referenced from:
  _readline_shell_run in readline_cli.o
  "_history_list", referenced from:
  _zif_readline_list_history in readline.o
  "_rl_mark", referenced from:
  _zif_readline_info in readline.o
  "_rl_pending_input", referenced from:
  _zif_readline_info in readline.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [libs/libphp7.bundle] Error 1
```

It seems like the PHP compile is not detecting the readline installation? How can I link them? Or at least, how can I troubleshoot this error?

I started with

```
php-7.2.3$ ./configure --without-iconv --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-pdo-mysql
php-7.2.3$ make
```

for default readline configuration.

When that didn't work, I downloaded and installed a fresh GNU readline in `/usr/local` with a default

```
readline-6.3$ ./configure
readline-6.3$ make
readline-6.3$ sudo make install
```

and the same `configure`/`make` for PHP.

When that didn't work, try more explicit reference to the `readline` installation location:

```
php-7.2.3$ ./configure --without-iconv --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-readline==/usr/local/lib --with-pdo-mysql
```

and then again looking for default installation location.

On the theory that maybe the `not found for architecture x86_64` part of the error was a clue that it was the wrong architecture, I tried to compile readline with

```
./configure CFLAGS="-arch x86_64" LDFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
```

But all these attempts gave the same error: `append_history` (and the others) is an undefined symbol referenced from `_readline_shell_run` in `readline_cli.o`

Googling the error produced many hits, but those with responses were almost all about using package managers such as `apt-get` on debian or brew or ports on mac. How can I compile and install from source on a mac? How can I link my PHP package to the installed readline headers?

Comment: If you are running python already perhaps worth looking at http://www.phpsh.org/? Sure you grabbed the devel package for readline? Sorry on mac I just use brew these days.

Comment: Where is this readline from that you installed? Can you share a link?

Comment: Try reinstalling readline `./configure CFLAGS="-arch x86_64" LDFLAGS="-arch x86_64" ./configure --prefix=/usr/local; make` Good Luck!

Comment: @ficuscr I downloaded from https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html. Looking at the page now, it seems a new version has been released in the last couple days. I guess I'll try it again

Comment: @ficuscr did you mean to give two configure commands, instead of one configure command with all three flags?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error and finally solved this problem by editing the Makefile which generated after `./configure --xxxxxx` command

Edit the Makefile and find `EXTRA_LIBS`, append the following`/usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.3_1/lib/libhistory.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.3_1/lib/`

so my `EXTRA_LIBS` looks like:

`EXTRA_LIBS = -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lresolv -lreadline -lncurses -lz -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lm -lxml2 -lz -licucore -lm -lcurl -lxml2 -lz -licucore -lm -lxml2 -lz -licucore -lm -lxml2 -lz -licucore -lm -lxml2 -lz -licucore -lm -lxml2 -lz -licucore -lm -lxml2 -lz -licucore -lm /usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.3_1/lib/libhistory.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.3_1/lib/libreadline.dylib`

just save it and run `make -j8 && make install`, everything works great again.